# Debugging Vala in VSCode on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, gtk3, vala

There is really no good documentation on how Vala and Visual Studio Code work together for a newbie to Vala and VSCode.

When trying to work with vala projects on the command line(Ubuntu 20.04), doing a build is as simple as running meson and ninja. What I am looking for is how this then maps to VSCode. Basically how do I take my folder of vala code with its meson scripts and integrate it into the build/debug system of vscode.

I tried the extensions available for Vala on the marketplace and I get syntax highlighting. Beyond that I am looking for how to get VSCode to run the meson and ninja scripts and debugging. Thanks!
(Trying to debug some GNOME desktop apps)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a definitive answer, but the integration with Meson build and a debugger is probably still work in progress.

There is a page on the GNOME wiki: [Coding in Vala with Visual Studio Code](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tools/VisualStudioCode). So if anyone has any experiences to share that would be a good place.

You should try a [Vala language server](https://github.com/benwaffle/vala-language-server). That will give more than syntax highlighting.

The [Meson Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davester47.meson-tools) VS Code extension looks interesting. Meson also provides [metadata in the build](https://mesonbuild.com/IDE-integration.html) that could be used if anyone wants to enhance these tools.

Vala uses C as its intermediate language and any debugging is done with a C debugger like GDB or LLDB. The Vala compiler will insert source code line references in the C when compiled for development, so the debugger will show the Vala source references as well. This is described in a bit more detail on the GNOME Wiki page referenced above, but this does need some tidying up in the Vala compiler. Symbol resolution from the C to Vala is more troublesome and I don't believe anyone has come up with a working solution as yet.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, you can try VS Code + CodeLLDB plugin, which generally works well for me.
The steps are as follows:

1. Add --debug option to valac. This can be done with "add_project_arguments" in meson.build
2. Generate a launch.json for LLDB. This can be done with "create a launch.json file" in "Run and Debug" of VS Code.
   [Create launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8F5C.png)
3. It will create a .vscode directory and a launch.json file inside it. Ensure that you have installed CodeLLDB plugin. Modity the "configurations" in the launch.json, such that "configurations" in the file becomes (`<my program>` needs to be changed to your executable file name)

```json
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<my program>",
            "args": ["-arg1", "-arg2"],
        }
    ]
```

4. Then you can set breakpoints and start debugging in VS Code.
   [Debugging in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTUOM.png)

Comment: Nice details, thanks for sharing. One point: the default [build type option](https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html) in Meson Build is `debug` and I believe this adds `--debug` to `valac` without needing to make it explicit, so there is no need to add it to `add_project_arguments`. When you want a to build a release then just change the `buildtype` in Meson to `release` and the debug information isn't included

Comment: Thx! I just got to know this about meson.

Answer (score 0):

It has taken some pulling together of various sources and trial and error but I have finally got vscode (version 1.87.2) to compile, build and debug Vala projects. Here's what I did.

I'm running **OpenSuse Tumbleweed**, but this solution "should" work for most distros.

1. I installed the Vala Language Server and the Gnome SDKs.

- I installed VSCode - from **flathub** - this resulted in some weird problems with the env variables - and it couldn't see any files in /usr/lib64 even with the path amended.

2. Install VSCode from your relevant repository (see [this link](https://linuxiac.com/how-to-install-vs-code-on-opensuse-leap-tumbleweed/) for OpenSuse)

**It seems that the flatpak sandbox prevents access to necessary libraries when doing a build with meson**

3. Next, I installed these extensions for VSCode

- [Vala (by Princeton Ferro)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=prince781.vala)
- [Code LLDB (by Vadim Chugunov)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb)

4. Then I opened my Vala project that I had started in **Gnome Builder** (open folder in VSCode and open your project folder)
5. Next I added **tmux** as the default terminal for VSCode (must have tmux installed for it to appear in the select list - you can just use the terminal of your choice here - but the autodetect list seems to be limited at this time)

- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type **"terminal select default profile"** and select the tmux profile when presented in the drop down list
- to verify press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type **"preference open user settings (JSON)"** and you will see tmux set as integrated terminal default profile (you could just use your terminal of choice here)

So now I have my terminal of choice as the default VSCode terminal - so far so good

6. Now we need to set a build task which is invoked with the VSCode shortcut of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>
7. Create a file called "tasks.json" in the `.vscode/` folder at the root of project (workspace) with the following contents:

```
    {    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
         // for the documentation about the tasks.json format

         //  default build task for vala project

        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Build",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "ninja",
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
                },
                "presentation": {
                    "panel": "new"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now when you build in vscode (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>) this task will run and build your project - any errors will show up in the terminal window

8. Next, we want a launcher task to run and debug the Vala project

When you try to launch the project from VSCode for the first time - it will prompt you to create a launcher.json file - do so

This file will also appear in the .vscode directory in the root directory of your project (workspace)

replace it with the following instructions

```
    {
         // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
         // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
         // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "lldb",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Debug",
                "program": 
    "${workspaceFolder}/build/src/${workspaceFolderBasename}"
             }
        ]
     }
```

Now you should be able to build and run your Vala project in VSCode

Let me know if I need to edit this - it worked for me but I'm reasonably new to Vala and the meson build system - I will update this if needed

EDIT #1

i have found it useful to add the following extensions to vscode - they help greatly and i highly recommend them (with the caveat that i have only been using them for a short time - but they do make it visually helpful as well as providing more utility when coding)

they are:

(i will include the http links once I have enough experience points lol)

- [Better Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments)
- [Bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks)
- [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker)
- CodeSnap
- Error Lens
- Git History
- Multiple cursor case preserve
- TODO Highlights
- Todo Tree
- Uncrustify

and finally

- [Tabnine AI Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TabNine.tabnine-vscode)

the Tabnine is especially interesting - it produces a human readable synopsis of your code from a highlighted code sample - see the attached example

[screen shot of Tabnine "explain" my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yt8q.png)